# getElementsByTagName('div') returns double occurrences

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I have two (2) div elements in the body.

```
<body><div></div><div></div></body>


var haha = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var k=0; k<haha.length; k++) alert(haha[k].tagName);
```

this returns 4 occurrences, I guess it's the close tags, how can I omit them?

Comment: Without your HTML, we can only guess.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case...Post your html too.

Comment: That's not something to conclude by looking at the code, it really is the case, try it and you will see. I was puzzled as well by the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem because of using a

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
for(var i in elements) {
    console.log(i) //This will print 2 x number of elements
}
```

instead of using

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); 
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     //Only once
}
```

Comment: Who invents these kinds of things. This must be the least intuitive thing I have ever seen. But it works, so have my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Disable firebug and try again ;)

Firebug and few other add-ons manipulate the html code. I tried your sample and got 3 alerts which makes prefect sense :

```
> document.getElementsByTagName('div')
[div, div, div#_firebugConsole]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are not properly closing your div. Maybe you miss the `</div>` forward slash

or maybe you are executing twice your javascript

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing close tags.

```
<div><div> <div><div>
```

should be

```
<div></div> <div></div>
```

cheers

Comment: You are right, didn't notice it :P. Thanks for the observation